# Djangoでサーバーが起動できない

Tags: python, python3, django

Django で `python3 manage.py runserver` と入力してサーバーを立ち上げようとしてみたのですが、日本語の「デスクトップ」が文字化けしているのが原因なのか、サーバーを立ち上げられません・・・

エラーは `[Errno 2] No such file or directory` となっております。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

カレントディレクトリに`manage.py`が存在しないのが直接の問題です。

ターミナルで`mypotoforio`ディレクトリに移動してから`runserver`してください。

```
cd mypotoforio
python manage.py runserver
```

※この回答はターミナルの文字化けに言及していません。